# How do I find out if the julia binary is linked against MKL?

Tags: julia, intel-mkl

I have used the following options when compiling (in the Make.user file):

```
USE_INTEL_MKL = 1
USE_INTEL_MKL_FFT = 1
```

Just to make sure it is indeed linked against mkl, I tried this:

```
~$ ldd /home/kaiyin/opt/julia-0.6.0-rc1/julia
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe85fec000)
    libjulia.so.0.6 => not found
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f748579e000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f7485596000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7485379000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7484faf000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000563aa3d8e000)
```

There doesn't seem to be anything related to mkl. Also, libjulia.so is "not found". Any suggestions?

BTW, I can start the julia repl without a problem:

```
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?help" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.6.0-rc1.0
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  
|__/                   |  x86_64-linux-gnu

julia>
```

Comment: what's the output of `versioninfo()`?

Comment: Ah, I see. That actually answers my question. I got `BLAS: libmkl_rt` from `versioninfo()`.

Comment: Could you write up an answer? I will be happy to accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`versioninfo()` is a useful function to get those kind of information. you could use `versioninfo(true)` to dump more.